# edit security settings of a .exe from cmd prompt

Tags: command-line, cmd, executable

Ok so I use Avira Antivir (do not comment if you are just going to tell me to get something else) I have the free version and i change the security settings of avnotify.exe, like many people who use the program, so i dont see the nag screen everytime it updates. But it seems they have been updating avnotify.exe when updates run too. so is there any way i could make a .bat file that changes the security settings so i could deny it read & execute ability?

I need to know what (if they exist) the code to access the properties of a .exe from the command line would be

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [icacls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx).